# weblogic10.3.4 ear deployment error

Tags: deployment, weblogic

We have migrated a J2EE application to Java EE and successfully deployed it into a Weblogic 10.3.5 server on Windows XP.

The same application we are also trying to deploy to Weblogic 10.3.4, this time on a Solaris based server. We are getting then getting the exception shown below.

Weblogic is trying to validate the deployment descriptor as J2EE, but it actually is a Java EE deployment descriptor.

How to overcome this issue? I also found that EJB and JSP support for 10.3.4 and 10.3.5 is the same.

```
weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.AnnotationProcessException: [EJB:015013]Bean class ae.co.etisalat.cbcm.cmmn.util.workflow.ejb.impl.WorkFlowEngineManagerEJB doesn't implement interface method: public abstract java.lang.String[] ae.co.etisalat.cbcm.cmmn.util.workflow.ejb.interfaces.WorkFlowEngineManagerLocal.getNextStateTransitions(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,ae.co.etisalat.cbcm.biz.util.persistency.PersistencyContext[],ae.co.etisalat.cbcm.cmmn.util.vo.ClientContext) throws java.lang.Exception.
        at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.addProcessingError(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:1323)
        at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.addFatalProcessingError(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:1328)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.dd.xml.EjbAnnotationProcessor.getBusinessMethods(EjbAnnotationProcessor.java:1371)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.dd.xml.EjbAnnotationProcessor.processAssemblyDescriptor(EjbAnnotationProcessor.java:879)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.dd.xml.EjbAnnotationProcessor.processSessionAnnotations(EjbAnnotationProcessor.java:785)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.dd.xml.EjbAnnotationProcessor.processAnnotations(EjbAnnotationProcessor.java:315)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.dd.xml.EjbAnnotationProcessor.processAnnotations(EjbAnnotationProcessor.java:185)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.dd.xml.EjbDescriptorReaderImpl.processStandardAnnotations(EjbDescriptorReaderImpl.java:344)
        at weblogic.ejb.container.dd.xml.EjbDescriptorReaderImpl.createReadOnlyDescriptorFromJarFile(EjbDescriptorReaderImpl.java:204)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making sure that if you are using @Remote and/or @Local and specifying an interface class that you make sure the actual Java class is implementing that interface.  This would at least give you a compilation error if the class does not implement one of the methods  of the interface.

This looks more like a Java error than a WebLogic error or underlying OS issue.  It's surprising that the same WAR file works on WebLogic 10.3.5 but not 10.3.4.  Perhaps its not the same WAR file that actually was working?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. we are using remote , home, ejb configuration in ejb-jar.xml, no annotations, we found some problem in the domain libraries. it solved , thanks again for the suggestion.